# Digital certificate for J2ME apps

Tags: java-me, certificate, code-signing, midp

I don't have any experience on using a digital cert.

Recently I wrote an application in J2ME and Qt for the Nokia S40 and S60 /Symbian ^3/Anna/Belle series phones.

My question is mainly on S40 J2ME phones.

My app need to read /write from memory cards and thus needs a digital cert signing.

I plan to let users download my apps from my site and my questions are:

- If I bought a cert, does it mean that I use the same cert to sign any number of J2ME apps? Or one cert one app?
- After signing an app with a cert, will it run after the cert expired? Suppose the cert is valid at the time signing the code. I read some articles about timestamp for PDF documents and Microsoft code signing, and not sure whether it is needed for J2ME apps.
- I assume many S40 users won't connect to internet. But when a user tries to install the MIDlet, is it necessary to connect through network to the cert issuer's site to verify the cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the purchased certificate to sign any number of applications until it expires
- Your midlet will still work and install but you will not be able to sign new ones with an expired certificate. See also this [post](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?94030-Midlet-signing&p=256353&viewfull=1#post256353)
- certificate validation does not require network access. The root certificate of the issuer is already on the device. Be aware that you should use a certificate issuer whose root certificate is on your target devices.